# How Can I Fix : DecimalFormat No Class Found Error // Solved

Tags: java

I am trying to make a new program which does calculate some numbers. And I use DecimalFormat in it. I started doing it in another computer. It was work fine before but when I switch the computer, I started getting this error.

I have use before this import

```
import com.ibm.icu.text.DecimalFormat;
```

When I  switch the computer and import my project to Eclipse. I get error because of that and have to use this.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
```

This is an example of the code:

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new java.text.DecimalFormat("0.00");
double number= Double.parseDouble(detay.get(0)); //detay.get(0) is a number like (123.456)
String number1= decimalFormat.format(number);
textField_1.setText(number1+"");
```

Program works fine until I click something has a event with DecimalFormat. Then I get this error:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/icu/text/DecimalFormat

Even if I delete the codes with DecimalFormat, I still get the error.

Note:[This was the  problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46FiW.jpg) . After I delete  all of them. Fixed.

Comment: First check if you are really not using the `com.ibm` class anywhere in your code anymore, and then make sure you recompile all your code. You must be using some class somewhere that still has a reference to the `com.ibm` class.

Comment: @Jesper I dont have any error in my codes. And checked all of my class and non of them has (import com.ibm.icu.text.DecimalFormat;). Only error i get is this and i dont even know what is that.[Link](https://imgur.com/a/ZXgtYg9)